# Unable to share image on Instagram

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api, android-sharing

I have developed an application that allows sharing images in Instagram. The application has no errors when executed but i cant share/upload images in Instagram. I could not figure out where it went wrong. Can someone help me with this. My codings are as follows:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.dothis.instagram;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    // listeners of our two buttons
    View.OnClickListener handler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.btnConnect:
                    createInstagramIntent();
                    break;


            }
        }
    };

    // our buttons
    findViewById(R.id.btnConnect).setOnClickListener(handler);


}



private void createInstagramIntent() {

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
    // setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
    share.setType("image/*");

    // Make sure you put example png image named myImage.png in your
    // directory
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/myImage.png";

    File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    // Broadcast the Intent.
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
}
}
```

ApplicationData.java:

```
 package com.example.dothis.instagram;

import android.app.Activity;

public class ApplicationData extends Activity {
public static final String CLIENT_ID = "###########";
public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "########";
public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "instagram:http://######/";
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.dothis.instagram" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-  permission>

</manifest>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Instagram OAuth</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>


</resources>
```

build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.dothis.instagram"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Any suggestions/guidance would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: did you have image with name of myImage.png ? in your directory

Comment: yes i do have..still unable to upload the image. @mina fawzy

Comment: write permission in right way <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-  permission> to <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: nope still cant upload image.i dont know where it went wrong. @mina fawzy

Comment: maybe this cause of authentaction  , please check this sample to make sure you in the right way https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-instagram-oauth

Answer (score 1):

please try this.

```
private void postinstagraminbackground() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String type = "image/*";
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                "com.instagram.android");
        if (intent != null) {

            try {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                if (file != null) {

                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                } else if (image_value != null) {
//incase of image url 
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, image_value);
                }
                shareIntent.setType(type);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mfinalmsg);
                // Broadcast the Intent.

                startActivity(shareIntent);

                // startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,
                // "Share to"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // bring user to the market to download the app.
            // or let them choose an app?
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                    + "com.instagram.android"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```